# Why does my script stop at parse_args() if -h argument is passed?

Tags: python, argparse

I tried to run the following script to know what's inside the namespace returned by `command.parse_args()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                 

import argparse

command = argparse.ArgumentParser()
command.add_argument("test")

print("test1")
args = command.parse_args()
print("test2")
print(args)
```

If I run a "complete" command (like `./test.py 1`) everything is ok and the Namespace is displayed.

But if I do something like `./test.py -h` it fails and stops at `args = 
command.parse_args()`, `print("Test2")` isn't called.

I got no error. But the rest of the script isn't interpreted.

Why?

Is there some kind of error this way?

Is `./test.py -h` invalid for some reason (Even if it seems to work fine)?

Does `args = command.parse_args()` cause an exit before the script's end?

Comment: `-h` means "show the help info and then exit". So it exits.

Comment: @khelwood It seems to be that indeed, I didn't know this behaviour. Thank you :)

Comment: The docs are full of examples (I counted 36 on the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) page) and that message is also printed when you call your script with the `-h` option. Kind of hard to miss...

Comment: @TimPietzcker I mean I knew for the help displaying but not for the exit.

Comment: The 'exit' part is burried in the 'help' subsection of https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, [help options are added](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#add-help) to the argument parser. Then, when the help argument is passed, the help action is invoked which will print the help, and then end the program execution.

If you don’t want that to happen, you need to set the `add_help` argument to `False` but that will also stop the argument parser from providing a help functionality.

The exit behavior is pretty obvious if you actually look at the help text that is printed:

```
-h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at argparse.py source code.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py#L1007

The argparse has the default help `-h`, which is an action to show the help and exit.

The `_HelpAction.__call__` handle this action.